# How to toggle all list items that are not equal to a specific text/category?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, filter, categories

I have a HTML list and want to filter for a specific category. At example my list is:

```
<ul class="myList">
  <li class="list-choose">
      <input class="input-choose" type="checkbox" id="[ID]" name="ID[]"/>
      <label class="label-choose" for=[ID]></label>

      <div class="subtitle">
         <span class="category">[category]</span>
      </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

(all in all there are about 40 list items, which should get filtered by category selection)

Now I want to create a category filter (in form of checkboxes/buttons/..) so that you can choose what category you want to display and hide all other elements that aren't in that selected category. My list items are created by an array ( a.e. [category]) so that the list item has its own category. But how can I filter only the selected category? I hope anyone can help me because my Javascript knowledges aren't the best.

Thank you!

I've tried this Javascript but it doesn't work:

```
function filter(element) {

var $trs = $('#myList .list-choose .subtitle input label').hide();
var regexp = new RegExp($(element).val(), 'i');
var $valid = $trs.filter(function () {
    return regexp.test($(this).find('label').text())
}).show();
$trs.not($valid).hide()

}

$('input, select').on('keyup change', function () {
if($(this).val() !== ""){
    filter(this);
} else{
    $('#myList .list-choose .subtitle').show();
}

});
```

Comment: _Now I want to create a category filter_ yeah you should

Comment: I tried it for about 4 hours now but it doesn't work

Comment: what issues did you face ? you can post the relevant code here for help in that

Comment: I've added my javascript code. If I try to search in an input bar or in a drop down category selection it doesn't work like I want

Comment: instead of doing this, I would suggest you to filter your data as per to catagory selected and then generate new html and append to DOM removing the previous elements